# ¿Cómo abrir un archivo desde un modal utilizando el valor de una petición ajax?

Tags: laravel

Tengo la siguiente tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que yo quiero es que cuando se le de clic al botón ver me abra en un modal  un archivo `.pdf` que tengo alojado en una carpeta llamada regulations
hasta el momento lo que he logrado es que el título me lo mande a un input :

```
<input type="text" name="titulo1" id="titulo1" >
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es  mi  código del script donde hago mi petición:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    Carga();
});

function Carga(){

    var tablaDatos = $("#datos");

    var route = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/generos";
    $("#datos").empty();
    $.get(route, function(res){
        $(res).each(function(key,value){
            tablaDatos.append("<tr><td>"+value.titulo+"</td><td><button value="+value.id+" OnClick='Mostrar(this);' class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>Editar</button><button class='btn btn-danger' value="+value.id+" OnClick='Eliminar(this);'>Eliminar</button><button class='btn btn-success' value="+value.id+" OnClick='VER(this);' class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal2'>Ver</button></td></tr>");
        });
    });
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es donde esta mi controlador:

```
public function show($id){

    $genre = Registro::find($id);
        return response()->json($genre);

}
```

Y por último este es donde esta mi modal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo puedo hacer para que el nombre del título lo pueda utilizar para meterlo aquí

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa bien [ask]. Las capturas de pantalla para mostrar el resultado actual y el esperado están bien, pero lo que sea código (todas tus capturas de sublimetext) debes ponerlas como texto para que podamos copiar, pegar y tratar de reproducir el problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya que quieres manipular el contenido del modal al presionar el botón, según tu código bastaría adaptar donde dice

```
$('#r').val(res.titulo);
```

Y poner en cambio

```
$('#r').attr('src',res.titulo);
```

Puesto que un iframe no tiene atributo `value` pero sí src. Ahora, pensemos que tu PDF está publicado en la web en https://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample-3pp.pdf

hay muchas maneras de poner un PDF en un iframe. Por ejemplo usando google docs para embedear cualquier url externa:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=https://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample-3pp.pdf&embedded=true" 
style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Usando un elemento `embed`:

```
<embed id="pdfdoc" src="https://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample-3pp.pdf" width="600" height="500" alt="pdf" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep2.html">
```

Usando un elemento `object`

```
<object id="pdfdoc" data="https://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample-3pp.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="500px">
```

Y en teoría podrías hacerlo directo como tú quieres salvo que eso te restringe a las condiciones de seguridad en que declares el iframe:

```
<iframe id="pdfdoc" src="https://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample-3pp.pdf"  width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
```

En el siguiente código te dejo un ejemplo que puedes reproducir en tu máquina. Lo que hice, a falta de tu backend que me lista los archivos y las características de un archivo en particular, fue usar el atributo `rel` para poner la URL del PDF. **No va a funcionar acá** porque los snippets de stackoverflow están con una política de sandbox muy restrictiva, pero puedes verlo funcionando en este [Plunkr de ejemplo](https://plnkr.co/edit/RZVA8EWObX9htviPHV4N?p=preview).

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery('.abrir').on('click', function() {
        var url = $(this).attr('rel');
        jQuery('#myModalLabel').text(url);
        jQuery('#pdfdoc').attr('data',url);
        
        jQuery('#myModal').modal({
          show: true
        });
      });
    });
```

```css
    .row {
      margin-top:10px;
    }
```

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap.js@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

  
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
      <input type="button" class="col-xs-3 btn btn-primary abrir" value="abrir archivo1.pdf" rel="https://www.antennahouse.com/XSLsample/pdf/sample-link_1.pdf" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
      <input type="button" class="col-xs-3 btn btn-primary abrir" value="abrir archivo2.pdf" rel="https://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample-3pp.pdf" />
    </div>

  </div>


    <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <object id="pdfdoc" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="500px">

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por responder me sirvio mucho su ayuda -> $('#r').attr('src',res.titulo);   al final quedo asi  en mi script  ->>>                                                                            var ur="regulations/"+res.titulo+".pdf";
 $('#r').attr('src',ur);                                                                                    y en mi modal asi ->>>>>   <iframe name="main" id="r" src="" frameborder="0" width="99%" height="95%" align="left">

</iframe>

Comment: Muy buen aporte, me funciono muy bien!! Ahora una consulta; estoy realizando una aplicacion que usa sesion de usuarios, en la cual a estos usuarios, otro usuario tipo admin, asignara un password general, es decir, un mismo pass para todos los usuarios; lo que me gustaria, es si pudieran ayudarme para que cuando un usuario inicie sesion por primera ves, me muestre un modal con un formulario para cambiar el password y que este modal no se cierre hasta que se de click en el boton guardar y se cambie la contraseña. Me podria ayudar?

Comment: @Francisco si tienes una nueva pregunta, debes crear tu propia publicación en lugar de responder con una nueva pregunta. Lee [ask] y [answer] y familiarízate con cómo funciona el sitio completando el [tour].